# Error when try to compute difference between two timestamps with Spring-jpa?

Tags: sql, spring, jpa

So, there is spring-jpa repository with such method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT user.endWork - user.startWork AS duration FROM USER_TABLE where id in (?1)", nativeQuery = true)
Timestamp getDuration(String id);
```

When I try to get duration between two timestamps, there is error about

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for
>   JDBC type: -104

But if I make this sql like this:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT user.endWork AS duration FROM USER_TABLE where id in (?1)", nativeQuery = true)
    Timestamp getDuration(String id);
```

It works okey without errors. How to compute difference between two timestamps when use oracle+jpa?

For addition info, User table is like this:

```
User
String id;
String name;
Timestamp startWork;
Timestamp endWork;
```

I use Oracle 11g database and JPA(Hibernate properties) is configured like this:

```
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
```

Answer (score 0):

But how do you want to diff them? It's not a number. You can calculate duration by getting full user and calculate like this :

> long duration = user.getEndWork().getTime() - user.getStartWork().getTime();